# This is a inefficiently written nested cursor. Can you replace it with a more efficient query that and explain what was wrong about mine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, nested, cursor

This is a question I have on a project and I just want to see what someone else has to say about it. Basically I need to figure out what it is trying to do and replace it with a more efficient query:

```
declare @Totalunitamount money   
declare @addamount money   
Declare @unithold int   
declare @oloop int   

DECLARE Jack_CursorOut CURSOR FOR SELECT h.salesorderid FROM SalesOrderHeader h

OPEN Jack_CursorOut;   
FETCH NEXT FROM Jack_CursorOut into @unithold;  
set @Totalunitamount = 0  
set @oloop= @@fetch_status   
        DECLARE Jack_CursorIn CURSOR for select d.unitprice from   
    SalesOrderDetail d where d.salesorderid=@unithold    
    open Jack_CursorIn;    
        set @Totalunitamount=0    
        FETCH NEXT FROM Jack_CursorIn into @addamount;    
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
        begin    
        set @Totalunitamount= @Totalunitamount+@addamount    

            FETCH NEXT FROM Jack_CursorIn into @addamount;   

        end     
    print 'Order number ' + convert(varchar,@unithold,1) + ' Order Total=' +
    convert(varchar,@Totalunitamount,1)
        CLOSE Jack_CursorIn;   
        DEALLOCATE Jack_CursorIn;   
WHILE @oloop=0   
begin   
FETCH NEXT FROM Jack_CursorOut into @unithold;
set @oloop= @@fetch_status
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to sum the total unitprice for each salesorderid. Should just be able to do a standard SUM grouping by salesorderid.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an overly-complicated use of two cursors and a while loop to perform the following:

```
SELECT h.salesorderid, SUM(d.unitprice) OrderTotal 
FROM SalesOrderHeader h 
JOIN SalesOrderDetail d ON d.salesorderid = h.salesorderid
GROUP BY h.salesorderid
```

Or, more specifically, printing a concatenation of each row that would result from the above query.

Probably also need an `ISNULL(SUM(d.unitprice), 0)` statement, too, in the case of no orders for the units, if that's actually important.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first cursor uses @unithold to iterate through all Sales Orders by their ID.

The inner cursor then iterates through the line items on each Sales Order in turn and uses @Totalunitamount to get the total cost of all line items on that Sales Order.

The output is a list of each Sales Order ID and it's total cost.

It's tricky to reverse engineer without a database/sample data, as it is so easy to miss some obscure detail, but it looks like the actual data (regardless of output presentation) could be fetched by something similar to:

```
SELECT h.salesorderid "Order Number", SUM(d.unitprice) "Order Total"
  FROM SalesOrderHeader h, SalesOrderDetail d
 WHERE d.salesorderid = h.salesorderid
 GROUP BY h.salesorderid
```

It's all a little odd, really, as it is so strangely written. Along with the fact that it seems to assess all orders ever, regardless of date, status, customer, store or any other factor.